# LightInject issue with DependencyResolver

Tags: light-inject

I've wrote the config for lightinject into a separate class.

In Global.ascx Application Start I have

```
 AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
 RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
 var container = new ServiceContainer();
 DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new LightInjectDependencyResolver(container));
```

My LightInjectDependencyResolver class looks like:

```
  public class LightInjectDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
  {
    private readonly ServiceContainer _serviceContainer;
    public LightInjectDependencyResolver(ServiceContainer serviceContainer)
    {
        _serviceContainer = serviceContainer;
        _serviceContainer.RegisterControllers();
        _serviceContainer.RegisterAssembly("mydll*.dll");
        _serviceContainer.EnableMvc();
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return _serviceContainer.GetInstance(serviceType);
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return _serviceContainer.GetAllInstances(serviceType);
    }
}
```

I get the yellow screen of death with the error:

Unable to resolve type: System.Web.Mvc.IControllerFactory, service name:

EDIT

I think I've sorted it, and basically I don't need the DependecnyReolver and looks like it does this internal. So you can still do stuff like:

```
IProductService a = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IProductService>();
a.GetById(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You figured it out:) The EnableMvc method takes care of this.

Check out http://www.lightinject.net/ for further information.

Best regards

Bernhard Richter